# Trying to access web/uploads/produits/img Symfony2

Tags: file, symfony, upload

I'm trying to upload a file and place it in my `web/uploads/produits/img` directory but the code bellow is not working:

```
public function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'uploads/produits/img';
}
protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}
```

I get the folowing error:

```
Could not move the file "C:\wamp\tmp\php9265.tmp" to "C:\wamp\www\Projet\src\Arkiglass\ProduitBundle/../../../..\web/uploads/produits/img\." (move_uploaded_file() 
[function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php9265.tmp' to 'C:\wamp\www\Projet\src\Arkiglass\ProduitBundle/../../../..\web/uploads/produits/img\.')
```

It's seems like it doesn't know the directory `__DIR__.'/../../../../web/'`...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem your entity lives under the entity directory, but rather directly under the bundles dir. Does it? So you're going up one dir to much. Two options:

1. Move your entity in the `Entity` subfolder, adjust namespace and all references. Standard symfony bundle dir layout.
2. remove one level of `../`